# Customizing the standard Serial.print functions in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, libraries

I need to test a bunch of arduino units and would like to change the standard HardwareSerial so it also sends whatever is printed to my UDP server. The communication to the UDP server works fine, no problems there.

I was thinking of copying the HardwareSerial library to my projects /src folder, but it seems that it ignores it and includes the standard library, even when using `#include "src/HardwareSerial/HardwareSerial.h"`. Stuff in there also doesn't get executed.

Replacing all Serial.println() with myUDPandprintfunction() should be somewhat simple but I got tons of errors (the sketch is rather big) and would prefer to just change code in 1 single place.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this? I've walked into major trouble with everything I've tried, and could use some advice on what would be a good approach. Should I just go back to fiddling with HardwareSerial.h?

EDIT:
It seems like the Arduino IDE includes Arduino.h at line 1, even if there's nothing there. That on its turn includes the standard HardwareSerial.h. Very inconvenient

Also, I'd like to to have my custom library file in my project folder so it's synchronised with Git

Comment: if you include Arduino.h the builder will not add it

Comment: Yes, but then I'm manually adding it so I still get conflicts.

Comment: Sounds like you need some method of "monkey patching". I've been looking for a solution to this on and off since I saw this question but haven't found anything promising.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Sopwafel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60973587) didn't work for me; I got some compile errors, eg. `cannot declare variable 'udpSerial' to be of abstract type 'UdpSerial'`. (and then it listed various "virtual methods" in the `HardwareSerial` class, ie. methods that had no implementation)

So here's the variation on it that I used. (for the Arduino Nano 33 BLE)

MySerial.h:

```
#ifndef MySerial_block
#define MySerial_block

#include <Print.h>

class MySerial: public Print {
    using Print::Print;   // Inheriting constructors
    public: 
    size_t write(uint8_t val) override;   // Overriding base functionality
    size_t write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) override;   // Overriding base functionality
};

extern MySerial mySerial; // Making it available as `mySerial`
#endif
```

MySerial.cpp

```
#include "MySerial.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

MySerial vs;

size_t MySerial::write(uint8_t val) {
    Serial.write(buffer, size);

    // put your custom logging code here
}
size_t MySerial::write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) {
    Serial.write(buffer, size);

    // put your custom logging code here
}
```

And then wherever I had been calling `Serial.print[ln]`, I now call `mySerial.print[ln]` instead. (inheriting from `Print` is done so that you don't have to redefine all of the overloads for various struct/value types)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Figured out how to do it properly. I wrote a header file like this:

```
#ifndef UdpSerial_h
#define UdpSerial_h

#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include "Arduino.h"

class UdpSerial: public HardwareSerial{
    using HardwareSerial::HardwareSerial;   // Inheriting constructors
    public: 
    size_t write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) override;   // Overriding base functionality
};

extern UdpSerial udpSerial; // Making it available as udpSerial
#endif
```

And a .cpp file like this:

```
#include "udpSerial.h"

#if !defined(NO_GLOBAL_INSTANCES) && !defined(NO_GLOBAL_SERIAL)
UdpSerial udpSerial(0);
#endif

size_t UdpSerial::write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size){
    myExtraFunctionality();
    Print::write(buffer, size);
}
```

Big thanks to @Delta_G for pointing me in the right direction

**Original post:**

For now, I am giving up and just writing a wrapper function prints to both serial and UDP. And then changing the ~100 calls of `Serial.println()` in my project to `UDPWrapper()`. With separately written overloads for every single type that can be put in it.

Better suggestions are still welcome because I don't like making ugly code

Comment: you only have to implement `write(byte)` in the wrapper if you inherit it from Print class. all other print functions are implemented in Print using write(byte). https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/0f3d4da614d5a195e03d70741031092a002e2d33/cores/arduino/Print.h#L51

Comment: To avoid having to write a whole bunch of separate overloads, look into template functions.  Instead of rewriting HardwareSerial, write a class that inherits from it and then you can add your wrapper function template to that.

Comment: @Delta_G aha, and then I'd use something like ```Serial.myUpdPrint(str);```, where myUdpPrint() does the extra things I want it to do before calling base.write()? 

I should really spend a few days dedicated to actually learning how C++ handles classes, inheritance, header files (those are so confusing) and stuff. Once I have time.

Comment: Yeah except you wouldn't call it Serial.  That's an instance of HardwareSerial.  You'd use an instance that you create for your class.  But you'd create it in the same way as Serial.

Comment: That was my second guess. I'll update my answer once I get it to work. Thanks a lot!